# Who's on Dictionary<>.First()?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the meaning of the .NET 3.5 extension method `Enumerable.First()` when you call it on an instance of the `Dictionary` collection?

Does the set of keys determine which item is first, or is it just not defined?

Comment: I'm no English major but isn't it "Who's?"

Comment: Cultural context: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sShMA85pv8M

Comment: Dang! Apparently you're closer to being an English major than I am.

Comment: Nicely phrased question.

Comment: +1 to the Editor! (just kidding).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I believe the set of keys *will* determine which item is first, but not in a well-defined (or easy to predict) way. In other words, don't assume that it will always work the same way - it's as unsafe as relying on a hash code implementation staying the same between runs.

EDIT: I believe that in fact, the ordering of insertion *does* matter, contrary to my previous ideas. However, this *is* implementation-specific (so could easily change in the next version). I believe that with the current implementation, the first entry added will be the first one returned *if* it hasn't been removed. If the first entry added is ever removed, the ordering is broken - it's not that the *earliest* entry is removed. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();        
        dict.Add(0, 0);
        dict.Add(1, 1);
        dict.Add(2, 2);
        dict.Remove(0);
        dict.Add(10, 10);

        foreach (var entry in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("First key: " + dict.First().Key);
    }
}
```

The results are 10, 1, 2, and "First key: 10" - showing that the *latest* added entry ends up being returned first.

However, I'd like to stress again that everything can change between versions of the framework.

Comment: This would mean the method is absolutely useless!

Comment: Not entirely. So long as the order is *stable* (without any changes), one could use First() and Skip(1) in conjunction to process a dictionary recursively. I don't know whether that's guaranteed or not, but one would hope that accessing the dictionary wouldn't affect the order.

Comment: More importantly, it's a general extension method which is used on any IEnumerable<T>. Yes, some IEnumerable<T>s don't have a well-defined order - but I think it would be slightly odd to differentiate between them on that basis.

Comment: Pretty sure that a) it will always work the same way and b) this isn't the answer and c) it will always work the same way but not in the way that you want.

Comment: I think my answer demonstrates not-entirely-contrived circumstances under which the method is useful.

Comment: IOrderedEnumerable<T> and IUnorderedEnumerable<T> - yuck.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the first item in a dictionary, you're best using a SortedDictionary. I would think the First() method will just return the first item which happens to be at the top, but not necessarily the first one that was added.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at some code that used a foreach loop to get the "first" item in a dictionary object. The code assumes that this is the first one added to the dictionary.

Initially I thought the Dictionary.First() method would be more efficient. But then I realized that the whole notion of what item is first might not make much sense in this context.

The SortedDictionary, which Echilon suggested, probably has more overhead and way more functionality than I need. I am leaning toward just save the key of the first element added.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more digging and found that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(VS.80).aspx) warns that the order of values and keys in a Dictionary is unspecified. So I believe that means that First() may not always return the same value as you add more values.

Comment: As you add more values it may very well change order, yes. It would be *allowed* to change order just based on having observed it, I suspect - but I don't think it does so.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering of the `Keys` collection in a class implementing `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not specified.  So you don't know what value `First()` is going to return.

But there's a reason to use `First()` anyway - or, more specifically, to use `FirstOrDefault()`.  If you have a method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` argument, and you know T is a type whose default value is `null, your method can use`FirstOrDefault()` to test the object to see if it's empty.

Why would you do this instead of using `Count()`?  To take advantage of deferred execution.  If you call `FirstOrDefault()` on a generator, the generator yields one result and stops.  If you call `Count()` on a generator, the generator has to enumerate to the end of the list.

So you can write a function like this:

```
bool ListIsEmpty(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    return list.FirstOrDefault() == null;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if (!ListIsEmpty(dict.Keys)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary is not empty");
}
if (!ListIsEmpty(dict.Keys.Where(x => x.Contains("foo"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dictionary has at least one key containing 'foo'.");
}
```

and know that the code is doing the bare minimum that it has to do in order to make those decisions.

**Edit:**

I should point out that another assumption the code above is making: that the `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a null as its first item!

This is always guaranteed for the `Keys` collection of a dictionary, or a `DataRowCollection` (my primary use case for LINQ), or for `Where()` when run on one of those collections.

But it's not guaranteed for a `List<string>` or a `List<DataRow>`.  So there are definitely circumstances in which you'd want to think twice before using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: I would use the .Any() method, rather than FirstOrDefault(), to get the same benefit. The default implementation of .Any() returns true if there is at least one entity in the enumerable.

Comment: Plus I don't have to perform a null check - .Any() returns bool. And your second example can become -- dict.Keys.Any(x => x.Contains("foo")) { etc }

Comment: You're quite correct.  Another reason I'm using FirstOrDefault() so much is that I'm frequently writing queries that have to examine the first thing that they find, if they find something.  It's less likely I'd need to do that when querying a Keys collection.