# The order of elements in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, ienumerable

My question is about enumerating Dictionary elements

```
// Dictionary definition
private Dictionary<string, string> _Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// add values using add

_Dictionary.Add("orange", "1");
_Dictionary.Add("apple", "4");
_Dictionary.Add("cucumber", "6");

// add values using []

_Dictionary["banana"] = 7;
_Dictionary["pineapple"] = 7;

// Now lets see how elements are returned by IEnumerator
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in _Dictionary)
{
  Trace.Write(String.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
}
```

In what order will be the elements enumerated? Can I force the order to be alphabetical?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the Enumerator of a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> return key value pairs in the order they were added? .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453190/does-the-enumerator-of-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-return-key-value-pairs-in-the)

Comment: Related: [Why is a Dictionary “not ordered”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The order of elements in a dictionary is non-deterministic. The notion of order simply is not defined for hashtables. So don't rely on enumerating in the same order as elements were added to the dictionary. That's not guaranteed.

Quote [from the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

Comment: But [there is OrderedDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary/4007799#4007799).

Comment: interesting that it's not just arbitrary, but as you say non-deterministic. build the same dictionary the same way twice: two different orders.

Answer (score 36):

You can always use [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) for that. Note that the dictionary is ordered by Key, by default, unless a comparer has been specified.

I'm skeptic regarding the use of [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) for what you want since documentation says that:

> The elements of an OrderedDictionary are not sorted by the key, unlike
>   the elements of a SortedDictionary class.

Comment: It's important to note that `SortedDictionary<K,V>` is implemented as a Binary Search Tree, which gives its operations different time and space complexity compared to the hashtable-based `Dictionary<K,V>`. If users need an `O(1)` insert/delete hashtable structure and also want to iterate over elements in key-order then they should to `dict.Keys.OrderBy( k => k ).Select( k => dict[k] )` instead (at the cost of `O(n)` space and `O( n log n )` time) for the `OrderBy()` (which will need to buffer the entire keys collection in an internal list).

Answer (score 33):

If you want the elements ordered, use a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-5.0). An ordinary hastable/dictionary is ordered only in some sense of the storage layout.

Comment: OrderedDictionary is in most cases wrong. It is neither Ordered by key or value, but by an internal Index. SortedDictionary is the one which is ordered in a way the user can manipulate (default key)

Comment: The question is asking about ordering in alphabetical order (assuming the questioner is talking about the key).  An ordered dictionary, if I understand the documentation correctly, will spit out the elements in the order they are inserted, i.e. not alphabetical, but using the internal index.  A SortedDictionary is probably the best fit for the user's question.

Answer (score 15):

The items will be returned in the order that they happen to be stored physically in the dictionary, which depends on the hash code and the order the items were added. Thus the order will seem random, and as implementations change, you should never depend on the order staying the same.

You can order the items when enumerating them:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in _Dictionary.OrderBy(k => k.Value)) {
  ...
}
```

In framework 2.0 you would first have to put the items in a list in order to sort them:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(_Dictionary);
items.Sort(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y) { return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value); });
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in items) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: When using the `_Dicationary.OrderBy(k => k.Value)` syntax ... does this alloacate a new object on the heap, or is this done in place?

Comment: @AmosEgel: It's not done in place, the dictionary doesn't have the capability to change the order of its items. It creates an object that can return the sorted result, but the actual sorting won't happen until you actually start to read from it.

Answer (score 15):

For an OrderedDictionary:

```
 var _OrderedDictionary = new System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary();

_OrderedDictionary.Add("testKey1", "testValue1");
_OrderedDictionary.Add("testKey2", "testValue2");
_OrderedDictionary.Add("testKey3", "testValue3");

var k = _OrderedDictionary.Keys.GetEnumerator();
var v = _OrderedDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();

while (k.MoveNext() && v.MoveNext()) {
    var key = k.Current; var value = v.Current;
}
```

Items are returned in the order that they are added.

Answer (score 5):

Associative arrays (aka, hash tables) are unordered, which means that the elements can be ordered in any way imaginable.

HOWEVER, you could fetch the array keys (only the keys), order that alphabetically (via a sort function) and then work on that.

I cannot give you a C# sample because I don't know the language, but this should be enough for you to go on yourself.