# switch case with integer expression

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to use `switch case` instead of `If Else` statement, in which i have to first check length of string and as per that i have to make cases of it.

```
switch (mystring.length)
{
    case <=25:
    {
        //do this
        break;
    }
    case <50:
    {
        //do this
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}
```

This is some thing i want to do but unable to get how to put `<25` in front of case because it is not appropriate as per switch case rules.

Comment: Why do you want to use `switch` for this task? Why is `if` bad for you?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/switch
Switch case requires each case be constant....

Comment: Please, read [MSDN switch (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov : i dont have any problem with "If" i am just trying either it is possible or not.

Comment: @kovilpattiCsharper : i know that why i mentioned it is not possible as per switch case rules.

Comment: @neerajMAX it's not...Any implementation of this task through `switch` would be at least less readeble and hardly better than `if`

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov : sorry to say but it is some how possible just check Habib's answer... :)

Comment: yeah, but it's still not a good solution. Just because it can be done doesn't mean it should be used. I would still use an `if else if`

Comment: @neerajMAX it's not a straightforward usage of `switch`, but a workaround.... I see no sense in it while having `if`-statement. Why doing simple things difficult?

Comment: @deafult: ofcourse it is not a appropriate solution. but atleast it is possible...
and you never know might be it will help you in future... :P 

B +ve & Think +ve :D

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov : to make thing intresting... although i am not going to use it in any of my solution... :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Its always better to use if/else for your particular case, With switch statement you can't put conditions in the case. It looks like you are checking for ranges and if the **range is  constant** then you can try the following *(if you want to use switch statement)*.

```
int Length = mystring.Length;
int range = (Length - 1) / 25;
switch (range)
{
    case 0:
        Console.WriteLine("Range between 0 to 25");
        break;
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Range between 26 to 50");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Range between 51 to 75");
        break;

}
```

Comment: what if range = 22/25 ??????? it will go to the default case instead of first case.

Comment: @neerajMAX, if the Length is `22` then it will go to the first case, since `(22 - 1) / 25` is `0`, its integer division :)

Comment: I would be very confused if I saw this in code. I would question the use of range and why an if hasn't been used.

Comment: @Default, that is why I said to use `if/else`, this solution is only here because it is possible using a switch statement if the range is constant. Just one possible way, never said its the better way to do :)

Comment: @Default nobody using it... it was just a thought came in my mind.. so i shared it with all the intelligent people over here... :)

Comment: @Habib oh.. right at the start, I completely missed that. better get some coffee..

Answer (score 19):

This really doesn't help the OP much, but hopefully it will help someone looking for this in the future.

If you're using C# 7 (Available in Visual Studio 2017), you can [`switch` on a range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

**Example:**

```
switch (mystring.length)
{
    case int n when (n >= 0 && n <= 25):
    //do this
    break;

    case int n when (n >= 26 && n <= 50 ):
    //do this
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not do this with `switch` but there may be a workaround for this.

```
Dictionary<int, Action> actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>()
    {
        {25,()=>Console.WriteLine("<25")},
        {49,()=>Console.WriteLine("<50")},
        {int.MaxValue,()=>Console.WriteLine("Default")},
    };


actions.First(kv => mystring.length < kv.Key).Value();
```

Comment: This solution can be extended to be more general. The first element of Tuple can be of type Func<bool> to provide more generic match.

Comment: I don't think this is reliable. [There is no order defined for `Dictionary`s](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4007787/382780), so any valid pair could be picked, not just the "first". This should probably be a list of `Tuple<int, Action>` so that there is order to the evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int range = (int) Math.Floor(mystring.Length / 25);

switch (range) {
case 0:

    //do this <= 25
    break;

case 1:

    //do this < 50 & > 25
    break;

default:
    break;
}​
```

Comment: If I saw this in code I would be very confused and question the use of `data`.