# C# Switch Between Two Numbers?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am trying to make an intelligent switch statement instead of using 20+ if statements. I tried this

```
private int num;
switch(num)
{
    case 1-10:
        Return "number is 1 through 10"
        break;
    default:
        Return "number is not 1 through 10"
}
```

It says cases cannot fall through each other.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not use a single if/else block with a condition that looks something like `if (num >= 1 && num <= 10)`?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13927939/961113

Comment: I would suggest using the tools that are in front of you for example `Google C# switch case statement syntax` also what is the method signature of the code belongs in Retun is a key word and is lower case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax for trying to do a range with switch/case is wrong.

`case 1 - 10:` will be translated to `case -9:`

There are two ways you can attempt to cover ranges (multiple values):

List the cases individually

```
case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10:
    return "Number is 1 through 10";
default:
    return "Number is not 1 though 10";
```

Calculate a range

```
int range = (number - 1) / 10;
switch (range)
{
    case 0: // 1 - 10
        return "Number is 1 through 10";
    default:
        return "Number is not 1 though 10";
}
```

### HOWEVER

You really should consider covering ranges of values with an `if` statement

```
if (1 <= number && number <= 10)
    return "Number is 1 through 10";
else
    return "Number is not 1 through 10";
```

Answer (score 17):

With recent changes [introduced in C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch), it is now possible to `switch` on a range.

**Example:**

```
int i = 63;

switch (i)
{
    case int n when (n >= 10):
    Console.WriteLine($"I am 10 or above: {n}");
    break;

    case int n when (n < 10 && n >= 5 ):
    Console.WriteLine($"I am between 10 and 5: {n}");
    break;

    case int n when (n < 5):
    Console.WriteLine($"I am less than 5: {n}");
    break;
}
```

**Note**: This really doesn't help the OP much, but hopefully it will help someone looking for this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm very late to the party, but in case anyone is wondering how this is done now, then have a look at this example:

```csharp
public string IsBetween1And10(int num)
{
    return num switch
    {       
        >= 1 and <= 10 => "number is 1 through 10",
        _ => "number is not 1 through 10"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no syntax for a "range" within a switch case.  If you don't want to list individual cases than an if/else will be cleaner:

```
if(num >= 1 && num <= 10)
    Return "number is 1 through 10";
else    
    Return "number is not 1 through 10";
```

which can also be shortened with the conditional operator:

```
return (num >= 1 && num <= 10)
    ? "number is 1 through 10"
    : "number is not 1 through 10";
```

I would use whichever is easiest to read and understand by *someone who didn't write it*.

Answer (score 1):

C#7 and above have added range operators to the switch statement. So now switching based on a range can be done like this:

```
    var myNumber = 71;
    var message = string.Empty;

    switch (myNumber)
    {
        case var case1 when case1 >= 0 && case1 <= 49:
        {
            message = $"{myNumber} is from 0 to 49.";
            break;
        }
        case var case2 when case2 >= 50 && case2 <= 99:
        {
            message = $"{myNumber} is from 50 to 99.";
            break;
        }
        default
        {
            message = $"{myNumber} is not in an acceptable range.";
            break;
        }
    }
```