# Sort on List with KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, list, key

I have this code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<String,List<MyObject>>> aux = retEmpty.ToList();
aux.ForEach(x => ret.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
```

I need to sort "ret" by the first element("string"). I tried a couple example but none of them work. Any help?

Comment: _What_ is `ret` at all?

Comment: How about `SortedDictionary<String,List<MyObject>>` ?

Comment: ret is "Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>". Sorry for that.

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you be more descriptive what would You like to achive ?

Comment: I need to sort it alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try replacing the second line with:

```
aux.OrderBy(x=>x.Key).ToList().ForEach(x=>ret.Add(x.Key,x.Value));
```

?

Comment: This won't work because ret is a simple Dictionary and the [order of elements in a Dictionary is non-deterministic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4007787/2504607)

Comment: Yes, I posted the answer before the comments on ret being a Dictionary.

Comment: Fair enough. I made my comment just to clarify for future reference.

Comment: @RicardoNeves Be careful using this method because it's just pure luck that a Dictionary returns values in the same order they where added.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you can simply use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var ret = new SortedDictionary<String,List<MyObject>>();
ret.Add(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
var v = from obj in ret
    orderby obj.Key
    select obj
```

Answer (score 0):

ret looks like a Dictionary. If this assumption is correct you could use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.