# Cannot convert keys or values of a dictionary to an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, copy

I have:
 `Dictionary<int, int> Color_Count = new Dictionary<int, int>();`

and also: `var sortedDict = from entry in Color_Count orderby entry.Value descending select entry;`

But I don't know how to fix this compiler error. When I am trying to copy keys from this dictionary to integer massive, like this:

```
int[] Colors_massive = sortedDict.Keys.ToArray();
```

It cause error CS1061:

```
'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,int>>' does not contain a definition for 'Keys' and no extension method 'Keys' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,int>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I am trying to copy, using other method:

```
int[] Colors_massive = new int[sortedDict.Keys.Count];
        sortedDict.Keys.CopyTo(Colors_massive, 0);
```

It also cause same error, but now error is printed twice. If I replace word 'Keys' in code, for word 'Values', it also prints the same error, but now compiler cannot find the definition for 'Values'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) may help you.

Comment: @Eminem Enumerable.ToDictionary will not help here as he needs it to be sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your statement does is return a IEnumerable (`System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,int>>`).

IEnumerable does not have a property called Key or Value. It only allows you to interate through the contents.

You are just ordering the contents of the dictionary by its values.

Try this:

```
    Dictionary<int, int> Color_Count = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> sortedDict = Color_Count.OrderByDescending(entry => entry.Value).ToList();
    int[] Colors_massive = sortedDict.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    List<int> orderedValues = sortedDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the other form of LINQ to keep the thing simple

```
var sortedDict = Color_Count.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

The `sortedDict` is then still a dictionary and you can access it's `Keys` collection

If you just want to create an array of keys, then it's even more simple

```
int[] sorted = Color_Count.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

Comment: Isn't the order lost as you convert the sorted list back to a dictionary?

Comment: @GaneshR. no, it isn't as you create the dictionary from the subset returned by `OrderByDescending`

Comment: Order in dictionary is non deterministic. It works in a test I created but not guaranteed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary

Comment: @GaneshR. I know, it could be different in another .NET implementation, but Microsoft has always implemented the dictionary this way.