# ObjectCache isn't preserving sort order

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, objectcache

I am storing data from my database into ObjectCache.

Looping through each row using a `for` statement whilst inserting a new object into the cache using `.Set()`

Data stores fine, except, its completely out of order than the original data set from the database.
How am I able to preserve the original sort order of inserting into the cache?

I want to avoid remaking the `Dictionary<string,object>` in the ObjectCache so that it sorts how I want after it's been inserted since it's a lot more work than I was hoping for. Anyone know how to preserve the original sort order when adding to the cache? Unfortunately sorting the key won't help, it needs to be sorted by a field in the `object`.

Comment: dictionary order is non-deterministic you would need to add your own rank value to sort the dictionary. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary

Comment: I think you can use a List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TObject>> to keeps all your items from db, then put the list into cache. When you do get from the list, order of items will not be changed.