# How to sort Dictionary of two integers not by using LINQ but using BubbleSort?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to sort Dictionary using buble sort. The problem i have is that i want to keep keys. For example:

I have dictionary looks like this:

```
{[0,5],[1,2],[2,3],[3,1],[4,9]}
```

After using Bubble Sort on it i should have Dictionary like this:

```
{[3,1],[1,2],[2,3],[0,5],[4,9]}
```

Is that even possible ?

Comment: do u want sort or trying to implement buble sort for dictionaries?

Comment: I'm trying to implement buble sort for dictionaries. But after sorting keys are not kept.

Comment: Something like this. I have to prove that i can write BubbleSort for Dictionaries if i want to use LINQ in future projects.

Comment: I am still unclear as to whether your intention is to write a sort program (in which case why specifically bubble sort?) or to end up with a sorted dictionary. My answer to you will be different depending on that.

Comment: As Oliver mentioned in his answer, Dictionaries are not ordered data structures. What you want to achieve is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries have no notion of order (cf. [The order of elements in Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary)), thus they cannot be sorted themselves. The two dictionaries you gave would be equivalent.

You could instead create a List of key-value pairs and implement your BubbleSort to compare only the second element of each pair. Like this, but using Bubblesort instead of OrderBy:

```
var sample = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    {0,5},
    {1,2},
    {2,3},
    {3,1},
    {4,9}
};

var keyValuePairs = sample.Select(p => new Tuple<int, int>(p.Key, p.Value)).ToList();

var sortedKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.OrderBy(t => t.Item2);
```