# How to order keys in Dictionary?

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int?,List<string>>`. I need to output pairs of keys and values sorted by keys in ascending order. First, I think to use OrderedDictionary but it saves both keys and values in type of object. Maybe somehow it could be done through the extension methods?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007782/the-order-of-elements-in-dictionary/4007787#4007787

Comment: [SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I was about to say that you can collect all keys in a List and sort them and then access it accordingly in ordered manner. Open to any kind of ideas regarding what is wrong/right with this solution.

Comment: Actually, do you only want a `List<int?>` only the sorted keys?

Comment: Yes, but I'll output both keys and values

Comment: People are trying to answer your question but they are getting downvoted because your question is not clear. Please provide an example of what you have and what you expect the output to be. Also, where is your code? Without code your question can be interpreted many ways.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I'd think the latest edit makes it much clearer. I've removed my close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Use a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>`/`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`:

   ```
   var sortedData = new SortedList<int?, List<string>>(currentDictionary);
   ```
2. Use Linq's `OrderBy`:

   ```
   var sortedData = currentDictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Key);
   ```

You can use any of these options with the following printing:

```
foreach (var entry in sortedData)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Values: ", entry.Key);

    foreach (var value in entry.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int?, List<string>> yourDictionary = GetTheDictionary();
var sortedKeys = yourDictionary.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).OrderBy(k => k);
```

This will give you a list of all of your keys in ascending order

If you want your dictionary the same. Ie still as Key Value Pairs. Just ordered by the key then you need to do.

```
yourDictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

Comment: OP needs the values too `dictionary.OrderBy(p => p.Key)`

Comment: Mm OPs questions is hard to follow, I'll update to include this though, thanks