# Sort Nested List and Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can i achieve Sorting of a  `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`.

I would like to sort the list on the basis of first element in the Dictionary.

My data Looks like

```
{
{{PID,A123},{SKU,TA50},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,C123},{SKU,TA52},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,B123},{SKU,TA53},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,A222},{SKU,TA54},{QTY,50}}
}
```

I am trying to get the output to look like

```
{
{{PID,A123},{SKU,TA50},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,A222},{SKU,TA54},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,B123},{SKU,TA53},{QTY,50}},
{{PID,C123},{SKU,TA52},{QTY,50}}
}
```

Solutions tried
list.Sort - Not working since the contents are dictionary.
list.OrderBy - Method not available.

Technology Working on - Visual Studio Community 2017, .NET 4.6.1, Console Application

Comment: Add `uses System.Linq;` to get `OrderBy`

Comment: "list.OrderBy - Method not available." - it's an extension method. Do you have `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Since Dictionary elements has no order, there is not "first element in the Dictionary".

Comment: @SananFataliyev Yeh i edited that

Comment: Using a dictionary if you need an ordered collection sounds like a code smell. It's order is not stable and you might get different results after adding or removing items.

Comment: @Rango what would you suggest for this kind of structured data

Comment: What version of `.NET` are you using?

Comment: @Fabjan i have mentioned in the post as well its .NET 4.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Linq [`OrderBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) combined with key access of the Dictionary `["PID"]`

```
items = items.OrderBy(x => x["PID"]).ToList();
```

so the `Dictionaies` are ordered, but themselves [have no order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4007787/1315444)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just wanted to know if i want to say filter this List and get values only where "SKU" = "TA50", how can i achieve that?

Comment: @AngadArora `Where(x => x["SKU"] == "TA50")`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sort list by dictionary key then

```
var result = list.OrderBy(dict => dict["PID"]).ToList();
```

You need to refrenced `using System.Linq;` in your program to avail `OrderBy` in intellisense.

Comment: Thank you for your time, as per the community if two answers are correct and same solution, i had to select the answer which came first. But thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @AngadArora, Glad to hear...No problem.. fubo's and my answer posted on difference of few seconds only...welcome :)