# Dictionary : Will calling .Keys be ordered consistently with .Values?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary, and call .Keys, and then .Values with no intervening operations. Will the ordering of the keys be consistent with the ordering of the values?

Put another way, will the nth key correspond to the nth value as they did before in the dictionary?

Comment: dictionaries are not guaranteed to have order.

Comment: probably its not clear, what you are asking

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453190/does-the-enumerator-of-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-return-key-value-pairs-in-the

Comment: @DanielA.White: The order of the entries wasn't what the OP asked about - he was asking about whether the keys and values would be in the same order, and the answer is "yes". So while you can't predict what the order of keys will be (given just the contents) you *can* predict that it'll be consistent with the order of the values.

Comment: No.  Especially if you have one key for many values like Dictionary<string, List<string>>.  The key for a dictionary is a hash table to reduce the time to extract items.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Will the ordering of the keys be consistent with the ordering of the values?

Yes, it's guaranteed by the documentation of both [`IDictionary<,>.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IDictionary<,>.Values`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x(v=vs.110).aspx).

`Keys` documentation:

> The order of the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the `Values` property.

`Values` documentation:

> The order of the values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` returned by the `Keys` property.

Comment: @OP: For readability reasons, I recommend against simultaneously enumerating the keys and values.  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so a cleaner alternative is `foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in dict) {/*code*/}`

Answer (score 5):

According to MSDN's documentation for [Dictionary.Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx), yes.

> The order of the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the `Values` property.