# C# Dictionary - Does adding same set of keys in the same order every time guarantees to be kept in the same order(whatever the order is) every time?

Tags: c#

*By same order, I don't mean the same order the keys were added!*

Say,

1) I've a dictionary d

2) I add 2, 4, 6 as my keys like

- d.Add(2, "")
- d.Add(4, "")
- d.Add(6, "")

3) Now I access it via d.Keys property

- Say, it returns keys in order 4, 2, 6

Now by same order I mean, If I keep repeating steps 2 & 3.

Will d.Keys always return the keys in same order 4, 2, 6.

Given the fact that the same set of keys(2,4,6) are added every time and in the *same order*!

*Basically is **adding keys** in dictionary a **deterministic process** ?*

I've run a few sample random cases, and it appears that *Dictionary.Keys property* returns the same sequence every time for the same set of keys.

But is it **guaranteed** ?

Sample code I tried

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            var fixedKeys = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(x => rand.Next(10000000)).Distinct().ToList();

            var dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            foreach (var item in fixedKeys)
            {
                dic.Add(item, "");
            }

            var fixedSequence = dic.Keys;

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                dic = new Dictionary<int, string>();

                foreach (var item in fixedKeys)
                {
                    dic.Add(item, "");
                }

                if (!dic.Keys.SequenceEqual(fixedSequence))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Order changed");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Absolutely not. The order in a dictionary is not defined.

Comment: No, there is no guarantee.

Comment: even if it was implemented that way now there is no guarantee it will be that way in the future since order is not part of the abstract data type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Enumerator of a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> return key value pairs in the order they were added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453190/does-the-enumerator-of-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-return-key-value-pairs-in-the)

Comment: @Adriani6 By same keys, I mean same set of unique keys

Comment: Ah, misleading title - I've read "Adding the same key" and assumed it was the same key. Apologies.

Comment: @TaW I've updated the question to make it clear, what I mean by same order

Comment: @FeRaaC No, that is a different question. I understand that the order of insertion and read is not guaranteed to be same.

Comment: I agree, this isn't a duplicate of the indicated question.  This question is asking, "if I get the keys, then get them again, will they be in the same order each time?"  That question asks "are the keys in the same order they were inserted?"

Comment: @vish the answers to the linked question do still apply and answer your questions. Meaning, the process of adding KeyValuePairs is deterministic, but the process is neither defined nor guaranteed (for future implementations).

Comment: @Amy Yes, that's what I mean, the only additional step is that I re-initialize my dictionary every time with the same set of keys before accessing the keys again

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> #### Remarks
>
> The order of the keys in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection` is unspecified, but it is the same order as the associated values in the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.ValueCollection` returned by the Values property.

The order of the keys is not guaranteed to be in any order.

Comment: I've updated my question to explain what I meant by order.

Comment: My answer doesn't change.  The order of the keys is unspecified.  The *current implementation* might behave a certain way, but you *cannot* depend on that behavior continuing into the future.

Comment: It may be unspecified in the documentation but if you only add to the dictionary the order will be the same 100% of the time. Its when you're adding and remove that order becomes inconsistent. Like the docs say, you shouldn't count on ordering when writing your code, but the order will be the same if you are only adding regardless.

Comment: @Josh `if you only add to the dictionary the order will be the same 100% of the time` That is how it is currently implemented.  No such guarantees exist going forward.  You cannot rely on *unspecified* behavior as if it has some kind of guarantee behind it simply because that is how it *currently* works.

Comment: @josh `as if the implementation for Dictionary is ever actually going to change.`  That's the point of a *guarantee*.  We have no such guarantee.  The word "guarantee" is defined as "a formal promise or assurance (typically in writing) that certain conditions will be fulfilled,".  Do we have such a guarantee in this case?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not guaranteed the keys will be returned in any order.

If you require this property, you may want to look into a [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

It is not guaranteed. The Dictionary is a hashtable and its concept does not enforce the reading to be in the same order as writing.
The order of elements in a dictionary is non-deterministic.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
>   a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its
>   key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

See 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4007787/194717