# Does Dictionary<string, int> preserves the insertion order?

Tags: c#, dictionary, preserve, insertion-order

I have been using C# for more than 10 years, but today I discovered that `Dictionary<string, int>` retains the insertion order? As far as I know, `Dictionary` is implemented internally using a hash table, so the internal arrangement should be in no particular order, but the test code below seems to show that the order during traversal is exactly the same as the order of insertion?

```cs
        const int N = 1000000;

        List<string> ss = new List<string>();
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            var s = string.Empty;
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
                s += (char)('a' + UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 26));

            //ss.add(s);
            ss.Add(new string(s));

            //dict[s] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1024);
            dict.Add(s, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1024));
        }

        int same = 0;

        var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            if (keys[i] == ss[i])
                ++same;
        }

        Debug.Log($"N={N}, same={same}");
        
        // the output is : N=1000000, same=1000000
```

Now I wonder if there is something wrong with my test code?

Can anyone confirm that the traversal order of `Dictionary` in C# is the insertion order?

Is it reliable?

Comment: Whenever I wonder about an implementation/behavior of a class I read the docs. Sounds very oldschool but surprisingly: *For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.*

Comment: The dictionary is a hash tree.  New items are added into the tree.  The data may be added into a list sequentially and a link is used to the hash tree.

Comment: And, if you do find that it appears to be kept in insertion order, don't bank on it being the rule. For example the debug implementation may be different than the production implementation. Consider the documented behavior to be the _contractual_ behavior

Comment: It seems very unlikely that one million random strings will be inserted in the hash table in ascending order by accident. This could be the case for a small number of items, but certainly not one million. There must be another explanation here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at the implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` (by clicking Alt-F12 with the text cursor on **`Dictionary`**`<string, int>` in Visual Studio). I do not understand it fully; however, I noticed that two arrays are used to store the entries:

```cs
private int[]? _buckets;
private Entry[]? _entries;
```

The `_buckets` are indeed accessed through the hash code. I.e., this is the hash table. By debugging I noticed that the entries are added in a random order into `_buckets` but in a sequential order into `_entries`. `_buckets` contains an index into `_entries`. This explains why the entries can be retrieved in the same order as they have been added to the dictionary.

This behavior is due to implementation detail. So, I wouldn't rely on it as the implementation could change in future releases. In fact, the implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has changed in the past. Also, I don't know if this order is always maintained, or if there are conditions where it might be broken.

---

Test setup: .NET 8.0 Console Application / C# 12

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    const int N = 1000000;

    List<string> list = [];
    Dictionary<string, int> dict = [];
    Type type = dict.GetType();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        string s = String.Empty;
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            s += (char)('a' + Random.Shared.Next(26));
        }
        list.Add(s);
        dict[s] = i; // Adding i simplifies analysis, as _entries[i].value now reflects the order.

        // Retrieve the dictionary's private fields at every iteration, since they are reallocated when they are resized.
        int[]? _buckets = (int[]?)type.GetField("_buckets", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(dict);
        object? _entries = type.GetField("_entries", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)?.GetValue(dict);
    } // <<< place a breakpoint here and inspect _buckets and _entries.

    int same = 0;
    string[] keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; ++i) {
        if (keys[i] == list[i]) {
            ++same;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"N={keys.Length}, same={same}");
}
```

Comment: You're right, this behavior is unreliable. Now I'm a little curious, what would happen if the order of the strings was shuffled before inserting into the Dictionary (meaning that the addresses of the strings are no longer in ascending order)?

Comment: Since the strings are random strings anyway, shuffling make no difference. A question is, what happens when entries are removed and then other ones added. Does this create holes? Are new items inserted into the holes or do these holes persist until a resize operation occurs? What is the effect of hash collisions? Etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses a hash table under the hood is correct. The observed behaviour that when enumerating your collection the returned order is the same as your insertion order often causes confusion, is purely coincidental and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed:

> It seems very unlikely that one million random strings will be
> inserted in the hash table in ascending order by accident.
> -Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Out of curiosity, I wanted to know what would happen if the strings were shuffled before inserting into the dictionary (meaning that the addresses of the strings are no longer in ascending order), however the test results were still the same.

```cs
            const int N = 1000000;
            //const int N = 100;

            List<string> ss = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                var s = string.Empty;
                for (int j = 0; j < 15; ++j)
                    s += (char)('a' + UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 26));

                ss.Add(s);
            }

            ss.Shuffle();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                dict[ss[i]] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1024);
            }

            int same = 0;

            var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                if (keys[i] == ss[i])
                    ++same;
            }

            Debug.Log($"N={N}, same={same}");
            // the output is : N=1000000, same=1000000
```

And what if the keys are ints?

```cs
            List<int> ints = new List<int>();
            Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            const int N = 1000000;
            //const int N = 100;

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                var num = 100 + i;
                ints.Add(num);
                dict.Add(num, UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 1024));
            }

            int same = 0;

            var keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            {
                if (keys[i] == ints[i])
                    ++same;
            }

            Debug.Log($"N={N}, same={same}");
            // the output is : N=1000000, same=1000000
```

Without looking at the implementation, I can't explain why this happens, but according to the official documentation, **it is unreliable**.

> For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as
> a KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> structure representing a value and its
> key. **The order in which the items are returned is undefined.**
>
> - from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453190/does-the-enumerator-of-a-dictionarytkey-tvalue-return-key-value-pairs-in-the)

Comment: Even if the items are always returned in the same order as they have been added the order is undefined by definition. Why? Because not defining the order gives Microsoft the freedom to change the implementation in future.