# c# Dictionary<string,string> how to loop through items without knowing key

Tags: c#, idictionary

I have a:

```
var selectedDates = new Dictionary<string, string>();
selectedDates.Add("2014-06-21", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-07-21", DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToLongDateString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-08-21", DateTime.Now.AddDays(9).ToLongDateString());
selectedDates.Add("2014-09-21", DateTime.Now.AddDays(14).ToLongDateString());
```

How can I loop trough items without knowing the key?

> For example I want to get the value of the **item[0]**

If I do:

```
var item = selectedDates[0].value; // I get an error
```

Comment: What do you expect the first item to be?

Comment: why use a dictionary then? Would an array or list not do the job?

Comment: Could you explain if you don't know how to loop over a dictionary or if you have problem to refer to a specific entry in the Dictionary without knowing the key value?

Answer (score 9):

> How can I loop trough items without knowing the key?
>
> For example I want to get the value of the `item[0]`

You want to treat the dictionary as (ordered) collection similar to a list or array and get the first item in it?

You can because a `Dictionary<string, string>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` implicitly. Just use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`:

```
string valueAtFirstPosition = selectedDates.First().Value;
```

However, note that **a dictionary is not meant to be used as as an ordered collection**. It is a collection which can be used to fast-lookup a value by a key. But you can enumerate it anyway.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string>keyVal in selectedDates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", keyVal.Key, keyVal.Value);
}
```

You should simply not rely on that order. I think in the current implementation the order is stable as long as you don't delete items. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436957/284240)

Read: [Why is a Dictionary “not ordered”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6384765/284240)

Comment: who upvotes this? "how to loop through items" and you say "use first"? this answer is wrong

Comment: @AndreasMüller: i understood "item[0]" as "give me the first item" and "loop trough items" as "use it as collection".

Comment: @TimeSchmelter question asks for something else. using [0] is OP's way of expressing that he doesn't know how to use a dictionary, and is refusing to read msdn api

Comment: @AndreasMüller: how do you know? OP is trying to find `0`(`int`) as key even if he adds `DateTime`s (as `string`)? Isn't that more unlikely as that he wants the first?

Comment: he is adding string keys and expects the indexer to work with an integer. No. If you're using a dictionary that's not what you would want. If he would want the first item he HOPEFULLY would be using a list instead

Comment: @AndreasMüller: He doesnt expect it to work, he just wants to use it like a list if he wants to access the first. That's why i've mentioned that a dictionary is not meant to be used as as an ordered collection. However, the order is stable as long as you don't modify the dictionary later (to be exact: delete items).

Comment: fair enough. In this case you probably guessed his intentions correct and he just doesn't know what collection to use.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  foreach (string key in selectedDates.Keys)
  {
        var item = selectedDates[key]; 
  }
```

Comment: though this is an amuzing way to do it, wouldn't a foreach(var v in sselectedDates){ var date = v.Value;} be better?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, loop trough it with a `foreach` or to get a specific index do:

```
var date = selectedDates.ElementAt(0).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me put together two things for you. Firstly, you can loop or use LINQ to access elements, just as you could do it in a list as well:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// loop
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    var key = item.Key;
    var value = item.Value;
}

// "first" (see below)
var firstItem = dict.First();
```

However, be aware that what you're referring to as the *first item* can be pretty much *any item* in the `Dictionary`. Dictionaries store elements in any order that is convenient for a lookup (so do sets).

This order is known for some implementations, but lists or arrays might fit better when the order of the elements is important. A `Dictionary` in .NET is an implementation of a [*hash table data structure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (tree map is another map implementation).

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
foreach(var key in selectedDates.Keys)
{
    var value = selectedDates[key];
}
```

Comment: As Vincent already commented at nsgocev's answer: *"wouldn't a foreach(var v in sselectedDates){ var date = v.Value;} be better?"*

Answer (score 0):

Use this overload of `Where`:

```
var result = selectedDates.Where((d,i)=>i==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach (var date in selectedDates)                
{                  
    var item = date.Value;              
}
```